# Finding Multiple Occurrences of a value in a Column. Then delete entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for the most efficient/quickest method to find multiple Occurrences of `"Bear*" or "Dog*"` in Column B, and deleting the entire Row.

Through various google searches, I've found instances with Arrays/UBound, and For i = 1. (I'm still learning VBA, don't understand these options).

I found an example of a `Do - Findnext Loop`. But I cou'dn't figure out how to condense it for the `"Bear*" OR "Dog*"`.  I'm also getting an error "object not found and don't fully understand the code to identify the issue.

```
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then

'Find Bear or Dog and delete entire row
Dim rngSearch As Range, rngLast As Range, rngFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

'Set the search range:
    Set rngSearch = .Range("B:B")
    
'Specify last cell in range
    Set rngLast = rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count)
    
'Find the string "Bear*" in search range, when it first occurs. Note that the After argument is used to begin search after the last cell in the search range.
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find("Bear*", after:=rngLast, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

'If "Bear*" is found in search range:
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

    'Saves the address of the first occurance of "Bear", in the strFirstAddress variable:
        strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address
            Do
                'Find next occurance of "Bear*". Note, that we do not start from the first occurrence of "Bear*" (ie. strFirstAddress)
                    Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
                        'Delete entire row
                        rngFound.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
            
                    'Object Not Found Error
                  Loop Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
      End If

        End If
    End With
Next Ws
```

So, I thought, would it be more efficient to insert a `.AutoFilter` instead?  But it acts like there's a filter, but nothing is filtered in Column B.

```
  Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then
         
         'Apply Filter
         .Range("A3").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="*BEAR*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*DOG"
         
         'Delete Rows
         .Range("A4:L").EntireRow.Delete
         
         'Clear Filter
         .ShowAllData

        
    End If
  End With
Next Ws
```

Comment: `A3:L` and `A4:L` are not valid range references. You need to include the ending row number.

Comment: @BigBen The ending row will vary.  So should I then do: `A3:L3` -> `LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and `A4:L & LastRow`?

Comment: Yes that is the approach to use, `"A4:L" & LastRow`.